# Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org

Tags: centos, terminal, yum, ethernet, modem

I did a fresh install of CentOS 7 on an Acer Inspire T.  It is a terminal-only installation (no GUI).  I connected the CentOS 7 box to a cable modem via an ethernet cable, and the cable modem is lighting up at the point of connection to indicate that the CentOS 7 box is connected.  But when I log in as root and type `yum install nano`, the terminal replies with `Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org`.

**What do I have to do in order to be able to successfully use `yum install` commands on this CentOS 7 box?**

---

**EDIT:**

As per @MarkPlotnick's advice, I am trying [the steps in this tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-network-centos-7/)

Typing `nlmcli d` resulted in:

```
DEVICE     TYPE         STATE         CONNECTION
eno1       ethernet     unmanaged     --
lo         loopback     unmanaged     -- 
wlp3s0     wifi         unmanaged     --
```

I then type `nmtui` and get the following screen shot:

[image]

**However, in the screen that follows when I chose Edit a connection, the only active options are `Add` and `Quit`.  By contrast, the `Edit` and `Delete` options are not activated so they cannot be selected.**

When I click **Add**, and then **Ethernet** it asks me for:

```
Profile Name:  
Device:
Cloned MAC Address:
MTU:
```

I imagine the profile name can be anything, but what do I put for the other three?

When I called my ISP, they told me my MAC address is in the format `11;aa11a1;a1;aa`, where a represents some letter, and 1 represents some digit.  But when I try to type this in the field for `Cloned MAC address`, it forces the format to be `11:aa:11:`.... and so on, where the characters are separated by colons at intervals that are different from what the ISP gave me.  Also, the ISP did not know what my `MTU` is, or what to put for `Device`.  So how do I find the correct values for these parameters?

Note: When I type `dmesg | -i Ethernet`, the terminal replies with `0.5056601 r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded`.  Does this provide information that we can use to fix this problem and connect to the internet?

Also note that `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1` was changed to allow `ssh` connections to a different computer when the ethernet cable is connected to that other computer instead of to the internet.  The contents of `ifcfg-eno1` are:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.100.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NAME=eno1
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=eno1
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
```

As per @garethTheRed's link, I changed `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1` to:

```
[root@example ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
DEVICE="eno1"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="eno1"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29209/discussion-on-question-by-codemed-could-not-resolve-host-mirrorlist-centos-org).